# gstreamer: interleaving 2 audios - link error

Tags: c#, c++, python, gstreamer

I am trying to interleave two audio files as given in the interleave GStreamer documentation:

```
gst-launch interleave name=i ! audioconvert ! wavenc ! filesink location=file.wav  filesrc location=file1.wav ! \
decodebin ! audioconvert ! "audio/x-raw-int,channels=1" ! queue ! i.sink0   filesrc location=file2.wav !  \
decodebin ! audioconvert ! "audio/x-raw-int,channels=1" ! queue ! i.sink1
```

But executing this command gives the following error:

0:00:00.125000000  2264   00332BC0 ERROR           GST_PIPELINE grammar.tab.c:656:gst_parse_perform_link: could not link queue0 to i

If I remove the second `filesrc` related commands i.e. all the command after "filesrc location=file2.wav, the command runs fine. What is wrong with the above command?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

try

```
gst-launch interleave name=i ! audioconvert ! wavenc ! filesink location=file.wav  filesrc location=file1.wav ! \
decodebin ! audioconvert ! "audio/x-raw-int,channels=1" ! queue ! i.   filesrc location=file2.wav !  \
decodebin ! audioconvert ! "audio/x-raw-int,channels=1" ! queue ! i.
```

the sink pads for the interleave element are request only, so i'm betting the i.sink0 pad does not exist when gst-launch tries to link the elements. leaving a single period (i.) tells gst-launch to try all pads until a suitable one is found.

for anything but the most basic examples, you're better off to create the pipeline manually in an easy high-level language like python.

see also

```
man gst-launch
```